# Matlab TreeBagger: Table variable is not a valid predictor

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use TreeBagger to build a classifier based on the UCI Diabetes 130-US database, http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Diabetes+130-US+hospitals+for+years+1999-2008.

I have imported the data as a table (letting Matlab decide on the data types), and have done some cleaning on the data. I'm calling the classifier as from an example, using my own data:

```
num_trees = 50;
B = TreeBagger(num_trees, train, train.readmitted,...
    'OOBPrediction','On',...
    'Method','classification');
oobErrorBaggedEnsemble = oobError(B);
plot(oobErrorBaggedEnsemble)
xlabel 'Number of grown trees';
ylabel 'Out-of-bag classification error';
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using classreg.learning.internal.table2PredictMatrix>makeXMatrix (line 100) Table variable is not a valid predictor.

Error in classreg.learning.internal.table2PredictMatrix (line 57)
Xout = makeXMatrix(X,CategoricalPredictors,vrange,pnames);
Error in classreg.learning.classif.CompactClassificationTree/predict (line 639)
            X = classreg.learning.internal.table2PredictMatrix(X,[],[],...
Error in CompactTreeBagger/treeEval (line 1083)
                    [labels,~,nodes] = predict(tree,x);
Error in CompactTreeBagger/predictAccum (line 1414)
                thisR = treeEval(bagger,it,thisX,doclassregtree);
Error in CompactTreeBagger/error (line 470)
                        predictAccum(bagger,X,'useifort',useIforT,...
Error in TreeBagger/oobError (line 1479)
            err = error(bagger.Compact,bagger.X,bagger.Y,...
train is a table, and table.readmitted is a cell retrieved from the table. Most of the rows are cells, as most of the data in this dataset is categorical.
```

I'm wondering is there are certain datatypes that the classifier can't handle.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of tables for the Machine Learning toolbox was introduced in R2016a. For previous versions, the data could only be passed to the fit* functions or TreeBagger as arrays.

The behavior changed from R2015(a,b) to R2016a.